# have problem in understanding the fourier series and eigenfunction expansion

Tags: fourier-series, eigenfunctions

Basically, I do not quite understand what does M look like and how does this textbook "easily verify the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of M"[image]

Comment: The operator $M$ applied to a function means take the negative of its second derivative, and it is easy to check that $M$ maps $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions to a multiple of themselves, assuming you know how to take derivatives of those functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $M$ is the map
$$
u \mapsto -u''
$$
defined on $W$. To check the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, observe that
$$
M\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right) = -\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)\right)'' = \left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)^2 \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)
$$
Likewise, you can check that
$$
M\left(\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right) =  \left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)^2 \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)
$$
In each case, we have verified that the function is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2$.

That these functions cover all of the eigenvectors of $M$ is a little less trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was always trying to imagine a matrix...